# CSES Sliding Cost - why is this formula for updating the cost correct?

Tags: algorithms, sets

In the CSES problem [Sliding Window Cost](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1077/), given an array and an integer `k`, we are asked to compute the **minimum cost** for each sliding window of fixed size `k`. The minimum cost is defined as the cost of making all elements equal. Therefore, it can be expressed as the sum of differences between each value and the median (considering $w$ is sorted):

$$ cost(w) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \left| w[i] - w[\left \lceil \frac{k}{2}\right \rceil]\right| $$

I have found a solution using an order statistics tree, for easily looking up the median of the sliding window in $O(\log k)$ time. This part is straightforward to understand, however the solution also uses an extra variable for storing the **previous median** (the median of the previous sliding window) to correctly update the cost of the new sliding window.

On each iteration, we delete the first element of the previous sliding window (`arr[i - k]`). To accurately update the cost, we also subtract the absolute difference between the deleted element and the previous median. At this point, the cost should be correct with respect to the sliding window elements which we currently have.

We then add the new element of the sliding window (`arr[i]`), and compute the new median. Here is the part which I do not understand. How do we know that performing this computation gives us the correct new cost?

```py
cost += abs(arr[i] - median)
if k is even:
    cost -= median - prevMedian
```

Can this relation be proven mathematically? What is the intuition behind it?

Here is the full solution in Java (OrderedMultiset is an equivalent implementation of PBDS, or order statistics tree, which correctly handles duplicates):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Kattio io = new Kattio();
    int N = io.nextInt();
    int K = io.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) arr[i] = io.nextInt();

    OrderedMultiset<Integer> slidingWindow = new OrderedMultiset<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) slidingWindow.insert(arr[i]);

    final int medianRank = (int) Math.ceil(K / 2.0f);
    long prevMedian = slidingWindow.findByOrder(medianRank);
    long cost = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) cost += Math.abs(arr[i] - prevMedian);
    io.print(cost);

    for (int i = K; i < N; i++) {
        slidingWindow.erase(arr[i - K]);
        cost -= Math.abs(arr[i - K] - prevMedian);

        slidingWindow.insert(arr[i]);
        final long median = slidingWindow.findByOrder(medianRank);
        cost += Math.abs(arr[i] - median);

        if (K % 2 == 0) cost -= median - prevMedian;
        io.print(" " + cost);

        prevMedian = median;
    }

    io.close();
}
```